# For loop isn't looping through the right number of times

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to print out "w3resource" backwards. Why is the loop ending after 5 times? It works if I change `i < stringBecomesArray.length` to `i < 10`.

```
var string = "w3resource";
var stringBecomesArray = string.split("");

for (var i = 0; i < stringBecomesArray.length; i++){
    var newString = [];
    newString[i] = stringBecomesArray.pop();
    console.log(newString);
}
```

Comment: Every time you call  `.pop()` the `.length` changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone mentioned in the comments, calling `.pop` removes the last element on the end of the string, making it shorter.

You probably want to use a while loop, like so:

```
var str = 'w3resource';
var strArr = str.split('');
var newStr = '';

while (strArr.length > 0){
    newStr += strArr.pop();
}

console.log(newStr);
```

Also, you don't need to use `.split`, you can access a string like an array. Using a for loop and reversed iteration you can do it like so:

```
var str = 'w3resource';
var newStr = '';
var i;

for (i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    newStr += str[i]
}

console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this it to actually go backwards though the word:

```
var string = "w3resource";
var newString = "";

for (var i = string.length; i > 0; i--){
    newString += string[i];
}

console.log(newString);
```